# Try to install Ubuntu - MD5 Check Sums Different

Tags: boot, usb, 14.04, live-usb, system-installation

So to start off, the reason I came to be in this predicament is because my desktop crashed. It was originally running windows 8.1, which I'm not too fond of. I didn't have the windows disk and because I've heard such great things about linux in the past few years I decided to give it a shot.

But too much avail my efforts have been in vein. I've been working on this the past 2 days and I've learned a lot but at this point I'm exhausted and don't know where to turn to.

I've tried to load Ubuntu 14.04 onto this desktop multiple times. I've downloaded multiple server copies from various sources, and even one desktop copy as well. I also tried downloading 13.10. None of them work. Each time I've loaded the iso file onto my usb using both the pendrive and unetbootin programs. When using the pendrive program, it seemed to transfer however it showed many errors in files copied. When I used unetbootin I got as far as loading it onto the desktop and getting a message saying 'invalid or corrupt kernal image'.

I've used the MD5sum checks on every file and none of the have equaled the same sum.

One last desperation try of loading it on (14.04 LTS "Trusty Tahr" - Release amd64 (20140416.2)), and my desktop recognizes it.The UNetbootin screen comes up and I select Default. I start to go through all the installation steps, (however without being able to connect to the internet at this point). It gets stuck at the "install the system" step. I hope you can feel my pain by now cus I just want this to work so badly.

I then go to "check the cd-rom(s) integrity". Integrity test failed "The ./pool/main/l/linux/pcmcia-storage-modules-3.13.0-24-generic-di_3.13.0-24-46_amd64.udeb file failed the MD%checksum verification. You CD-ROM or this file may have been corrupted"

Can anyone help with this PLEASE!? I don't want to have to go back to windows 8 haha. Does anyone have any advice on whether being able to hook up to the internet would allow me to repair those problems? - probably not but I thought I'd ask

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know why the Windows 8 installation crashed in the first place?

I think you should run memtest86+ on your desktop.  Bad memory could result in all kinds of strange issues with random crashes and corrupt file systems.

Comment: The guy i took it into, I actually just spoke with on the phone again. He originally said the problems might be coming from driver issues on Windows, however he said that I definitely should be able to install Linux.

Is the biggest problem not that the MD5sum isn't equal?

Comment: The MD5sum check failing means that the data when read from the CD isn't correct.  This could be because of a burning problem, downloading/network problem or memory problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download this [ISO file](http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso)
2. [Check MD5Sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#Check_the_iso_file)
3. Then [burn it on a DVD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto) or create a [bootable USB drive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
4. [Check MD5Sum of your DVD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)
5. [Follow this guide: Installing Ubuntu Quickly and Easily via Trial and Error (start at point 2)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Comment: I'll let you know as soon as I finish it. This may help. The server copies I downloaded previously were only 564 MB and the desktop copy was only 7.99MB now that I've checked.

Comment: This download you linked is extremely slow, it's going to take a whole day before this finishes.

Comment: No i've tried it, its the official server and i get full speed. It must be your connection. What is your DSL speed? You can use a Download manager like [DownloadThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/downthemall/) then you can pause it if you want.

Comment: Actually that was a mistake before, I apologize. It has downloaded completely. The File size is 964 MB however the md5sum doesn't match up. dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153 I get this hash. Not that that would mean anything to you though.

Comment: `dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153` is the correct md5sum for the `ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso` what did you get?

Comment: the win md5sum told me was it incorrect. But I see now that you're correct.
I've actually made some great progress now. I've gone as far as installing it onto my desktop, but basically everytime I restart I have to start from basically scratch.

Comment: What does "basically scratch" mean, sorry i dont't understand this. Can you describe it in other words?

Comment: I should have been more specific sorry. After it says the installation is complete and I'm done "trying" the os, it asks to restart for the installation to be complete. Then from here, I can't get it to load up regularly without my USB which had the original ubuntu iso file on it.

Comment: You can try [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) (2nd option) if this not works please ask a new question with the output from boot-repair.

Comment: I think I may have solved the problem. There was an issue with the boot order. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Good to hear, hoping the next experiences with Ubuntu will be better.